# Why doesn't decimal.getcontext().prec=3 work for decimal.Decimal(1.234)

Tags: python, decimal-precision

Why doesn't decimal.getcontext().prec for decimal.Decimal(x)? It gives a long decimal value:

```
>>>decimal.getcontext().prec = 3

>>>decimal.Decimal(2.345)
Decimal('2.345000000000000195399252334027551114559173583984375')
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 1):

As documented in the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial),

> The significance of a new Decimal is determined solely by the number of digits input. Context precision and rounding ***only*** come into play during arithmetic operations.

```
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 3
>>> decimal.Decimal(2.345)
Decimal('2.345000000000000195399252334027551114559173583984375')
>>> decimal.Decimal(2.345) + decimal.Decimal(4)
Decimal('6.35')
```